# C# Crystal report argument out of range exception

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report @c# program but when I execute the report its working at first but when I execute the same report at second time I am having this error.

I use view to sql server to retrieve my data.

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From referral where referralNo = '" + 
 lblReferral.Text + "' and clientNo = '" + cbClientNo.Text + "'", con);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 da.SelectCommand = cmd;
 da.Fill(ds, "referral");
 rp.SetDataSource(ds);
 f3.crt.ReportSource = rp;   
 f3.Show();
 rp.Close();
```

I am having this error.

```
 An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' 
 occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

 Additional information: Index 0 is out of range.
```

then these are the instances

```
 CrystalReport1 rp = new CrystalReport1();
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 reportViewer f3 = new reportViewer();
```

[Error @reviewing the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoTlM.png)

Comment: where is the report instance created (`crt`)? is it a control that was added to f3 at design time? try to get the full exception call stack and post it here. *usual hint the code is not safe for scripting, users could inject malicious code if text in lblreferral or cbclientno is editable*

Comment: thanks for the advice the  crt their is the crystal report and the f3 is the form used for the reportviewer i am using a view to get all of those data then the lblreferral is autogenerate number and cbclient is combobox that stores clientno only

Comment: ok do you create a new instance of everything before you run the second time, or are you re-using the existing instances?

Comment: yes, but when i run the report at first it works but in the second time i am getting that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my problem, it prompts an argument exception because the program, I called form via `form.Show()` instead `form.ShowDialog()`.